# In ggmap/ggplot, how to set size in absolute not relative values

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

In the following simplified example, the size variable controls the relative size of lines to be plotted on the map with `geom_path`.

The problem is that apparently the size is not in millimeters (as in documentation for ggplot), but for any two or more values in size variable, the lines with two extremes (min and max) are plotted with minimal and greatest width available and all the other lines are on discrete scale somewhere in the middle.

The greatest width is just too wide and I wanted to make it thinner. But since the size appear to be relative to min/max and is not an absolute (millimeter/pixel whatever) value, I am unable to control the actual size.

Please change the `somevalue` here and see that nothing changes between plots.

```
library(ggmap)

base_layer <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 28.5, lat = 37) , zoom = 3 , maptype="roadmap" , size = c(640,640) , scale = 2 , color = "bw")

somevalue <- 3

df <- data.frame(
  group = c("g1","g1","g2","g2"), 
  size = c(1,1,somevalue,somevalue), 
  color = c("blue","blue", "red", "red"),
  lon = c(10,20,10,-10),
  lat = c(52,60,52,60)
)

ggmap(base_layer) + 
  geom_path(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, alpha = 0.6, group = group, color = color, size = size))
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the size in two ways:

1) You can disable the automatic rescaling by using `scale_size_identity`.

2) You can manually set the size `range` by using `scale_size_continuous`.

Option 1) will scale with your data values, option 2) will not.

Both of these give the same plot:

```
ggmap(base_layer) + 
  geom_path(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = group, color = color, size = size),
            alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_size_identity()

ggmap(base_layer) + 
  geom_path(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = group, color = color, size = size),
            alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 3))
```

[image]

p.s. Note that one needs to place the `alpha` value *outside* the `aes`, when setting it to a constant.